# Prevent focusing close button when Enter key is pressed

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm handling myDialog1_KeyDown event, and if Enter key is pressed my method moves focus to the next element like this:

```
UIElement focusedElement = Keyboard.FocusedElement as UIElement;
if (focusedElement != null)
{
    if(focusedElement.MoveFocus(newTraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next)))
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

myDialog1 is myDockBase object. myDockBase is a class which extends DXWindow and is used for every modal dialog in the app.

Then problem is when user is positioned on the last field - when he press Enter key focus is moved to the close button (minimize and maximize buttons are hidden) and then if he press Enter again the window is closed.

EDIT: What I want: if close button is focused don't allow user to close window on pressing enter key or don't move focus to close button

Comment: This is a strong violation of UI standards.  Tick the IsDefault property for the Close button so pressing Enter always closes the dialog.

Answer (score 5):

A solution might be to forbid the close button to have focus at all, assuming you don't need it. See [Focusable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.iinputelement.focusable.aspx) property. If you create the button in code: `closeButton.Focusable = false`. If in XAML: `<Button Focusable="false" Command="...">Close</Button>`. This way when you navigate focus the close button won't appear in the cycle.

Comment: i know this solution, but it works only if i create button in xaml. better solution is to set IsTabStop="False", then the button is focusable by mouse, and not by keyboard. but, i need to do this on a standard Windows close button (in the top right corner of the window).

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what you expect to happen.  You could check if the current control is the last field (you must have an ID for it).  If the user is currently in that last field, don't move forward to the next field.

Comment: i added what i expect to happen to my question. i could test if currently focused field is the last field, but then i need to do this on every form (+adding name to last field). i'm looking for a more elegant solution

Comment: You could put the functionality in a parent class, inherit from it.  Make sure you give the Close button the same ID throughout.

Comment: yes, but i can't get the close button property in my classes, and it's hidden in the designer. maybe i could try to add a last field which is transparent and that moves focus to the first field on enter key press.